# What are the Apache Flink non-intensive vs intensive tasks?

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have been learning Apache Flink.

At the part of [Task Slots and Resources](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/concepts/runtime.html#task-slots-and-resources), how the subtasks are allocated into task slots within TaskManager is discussed.

> "It is easier to get better resource utilization. Without slot sharing, the **non-intensive** *source/map()* subtasks would block as many resources as the resource **intensive** window subtasks."

What are the non-intensive vs intensive tasks and what are their different characteristics?